# C# Bruteforce - Multithreading a fixed length password

Tags: c#, multithreading, passwords, brute-force

I have been working on an algorithm to do Brute Forcing. Its more of a personal interest than for any malicious use tbh. I've always been interested in cryptography and security.
I have one mode on the application that will create worker threads to exercise the possible combinations for a given length (1 thread per length).

Eg: You start the process - then it will start with length 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and so on.
As the lower length threads complete, it will then increase the suspected password length by 1 and spawn a new thread.
The limiting factor being ProcessorCount -1 (To avoid thread locking or GUI thread getting frozen: Generally found the system more stable with a free core)

So on a 4 core system, you will be working on Password lengths 1-3, when 1,2 and 3 are done, it will then move on to 4,5,6 and so on.
Lengths 1-5 finish practically instantly.
6-7 within 3-4 seconds.
Length 8 takes maybe 30-45 seconds. 
(These times depend on whether it is numerical / alphanumeric etc)
More possible characters increase the keyspace we need to check.

OK, so that is one method of multi threading it.
But the other method I want to introduce is a little more complex.
It involves using multiple threads to exercise the full key-space of a fixed suspected length password.
Eg: We know it is 8 digits long, so use all of our threads to get through the 8 digit password keyspace faster.

I am unsure how to proceed.

Eg:
Lets imagine our password is 100 (1000 combinations?)
We have 8 cores on our processor
So that's 7 potential threads -if we go with my -1 approach.
That works out to roughly 143 combinations to test per thread.
I am just wondering how to efficiently calculate the starting position for each thread.

Eg:

Thread 1 would start with 000 and end at 142
Thread 2 would start with 143 and end at 285 etc

This sounds easy with Numbers, but when you are using an array of possible characters - 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890'
How does one work out the start and end points?
With 36 possible characters in that string.
Would it be 36 x 36 x 36 = 46656 character combinations for a 3 letter password?

Ok, so if I have 7 threads working on 6666 combinations each.
How do I take those start and end positions and translate them into comparison strings.

**I guess my main question is this**:
How do I turn the combination index into a string constructed from the available characters?

Eg:

- 1 would likely be 'a'
- 2 would be 'b'
- 37 would probably be 'ab' etc

Comment: Have you read this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963552.aspx

Comment: If 'a' is a possibility and the brute force calculation was looking for a 3 character long password it would require ' '(an open space) to be in your possible character list as well otherwise it would never get there. it would start with 'aaa' another problem is if you do add it in your list then a possible password could be 'a  ' and ' a ' so you need to take this in consideration

Comment: Yes, the number of possible k-letter words with n symbols is n^k. For example, there are 10 decimal digits and the number of possible 3-digit numbers is ... 10^3. Your brute force method is going to take a while even before you get to 10-character passwords. 36^7 is 78 billion and change.

Comment: As for how to turn the index into a string, that's easy. Do a base conversion. That is, output your number in base 36. The algorithm's no different than converting to any other base.

Answer (score 0):

Would not advise you in doing this but if this is the way you want to go then think about it like this

You have 36 possibilities on character 1 and 36 on character 2 for each possibility on character 1. Same thing would go for character 3 .
So. . .
Take the first character's possibilities and devide that by 6(thread) (7 will be messy)
 Gives you 6 per thread
This is then 6 different possibilites of character 1 that has 36X36 possibities 

That means thread 1 does all those that starts with a,b,c,d,e and f

Thread 2 then will do g,h,i,j,k and l

and so on

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having each thread search exactly 1/*n*th of the search space, consider chopping it up into 'logical' pieces (i.e. that make sense to *you*). It means you will create more jobs than you have cores, and each of your threads can just pick up one of the jobs once it has finished the previous one.

E.g. for numeric 8-digit passwords, you could create tasks 0 up to 9, where task *n* is "search all 8-digit passwords starting with digit *n*". For alphanumeric passwords, you can create 36 tasks: "search all passwords starting with 'a'", "... starting with 'b'", ..., "starting with '0'".

Throw all tasks into a pool, fire up as many threads as you want and give them a task from the pool. As soon as the task finishes, have the thread take a new task from the pool,  until it is exhausted.

You could use a [Thread Pool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as.aspx) for this, but frankly I would just create a simple mechanism myself, where the pool of work is a `List<Action>` and you use a simple `lock`ing mechanism to pull tasks off the list once the previous action finishes.

---

*Edit*: Whipped up a quick example. It looks like a lot of code but it's fairly simple. Not really tested, but should give you a clue what I mean.

```
private List<Action> jobs = new List<Action>();
private object jobsLock = new object();

// This is the CPU-intensive function that does the actual work of checking passwords
private void TestPasswords(int length) {
    for(int i = 0; i < (1 << length); i++)
    {
        // Simulate testing the password.
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}

// Each thread is dispatched with this action.
// It keeps pulling jobs from the queue and executing them until no more remain.
private void DoWork()
{
    while(true)
    {
        Action job = null;
        lock(this.jobsLock)
        {
            if(this.jobs.Count == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            job = this.jobs[0];
            this.jobs.RemoveAt(0);
        }

        if(job != null)
        {
            job();
        }
    }
}

// Tester method
public void Run()
{
    // For all password lengths from 1 to 8, generate a job to test passwords.
    // You probably want to divide these differently (e.g. let i be the job that tests
    // all 1 - 8 character passwords starting with the character i, such that
    // all jobs are approximately of equal length).
    for(int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
    {
        int length = i;
        this.jobs.Add(() => TestPasswords(length));
    }

    // Create a background thread for each of the cores except one, 
    // and let them execute the DoWork loop until the queue is empty.
    // You may build a ContinueWith or WaitAll mechanism to catch the results
    // and build some callback stuff to get the progress.
    int numberOfCores = 8;
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfCores - 1; i++)
    {
        Task.Run(DoWork);
    }
}
```